# UILocalNotification play sound from app documents

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I know that `UILocalNotification` supports `soundName` only from app bundle, but I saw program that plays my recorded sound in Notification, even if program is closed. How to implement it? Any ideas is very important for me..

Comment: The ../Documents/sound.caf method used to work, but I think it may be broken in iOS 6 beta. Can any other devs verify? I would have left this as a comment if I could.

Comment: Having the same issue, were you able to resolve this? I know this thread is a couple years old but maybe you can offer some insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A surefire way to get an `NSURL` to the application documents directory is like this...

```
NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
```

Then you can get an `NSURL` reference to your sound file like this...

```
NSURL *soundURL = [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];
```

If you need a string representation of the path to the resource at that URL you can obtain it like this...

```
NSString *pathRepresentation = [soundURL absoluteString];
```

Comment: Hi Mark, I tried this but it didn't work in my app? I have recorded .m4a file in document directory. Is there any other things to take care?

Comment: Hi @Meghan, if I recall correctly, the file needs to be a .caf to be played as a short sound. Here's some more info on converting audio files for use on iOS. http://gamua.com/blog/2010/06/sound-on-ios-best-practices/

Comment: I have tested m4a file bundle, but My problem is I have a file in documents directory, and I want to set it as a UILocalnotification sound.

Answer (score 1):

I checked next method work on ios 5.0.1:

just setup relative path like this

```
notify.soundName = @"../Documents/blabla.caf"
```